# Options for rendering a user control in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

How can I render a user control in asp.net mvc?

is my only option to use the mvctoolkit?

I am using mvc 2.0 now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of user controls in ASP.NET MVC are partials, which are shared views.

MVC Toolkit does seem to be the closest approach I've seen, but what's wrong with using `RenderPartial` instead?

**Further:**

In [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/davidebb/archive/2010/01/13/take-your-mvc-user-controls-to-the-next-level.aspx) article, David Ebbo (creator of [T4MVC](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4mvc)) discusses user controls in ASP.NET MVC. Have a look at this and see if anything in there might be useful to your situation.

Comment: Every day again and again I see how extremely powerful RenderPartial() and RenderAction() helpers are. You just have to know when to use one over the another. So I agree with Dan 100%.

Comment: I think your answer could be rephrased to not include a question.

Comment: The question was intended to create feedback in the hopes of clarifying the OP's question. The use of RenderPartial seems to be something that Blankman may have missed.